# Approximation smooth functions ( Freidrichs)

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

i am trying understand the SOBOLEV SPACES (TOPICS IN FUNCTIONAL ANALYSIS AND APPLICATIONS) BY s KESAVAN

i am new to this topic can you some help understand

[image]

[image]

from the circle  i understand that we get that functions by cut of functions can someone explain rest of things please

Comment: What is the exact question?

Comment: @Fritzt.. the circle one